# Authenticate custom api with Windows Integrated Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core based API that is hosted on Azure websites (endpoint eg. myapi.azurewebsites.net).
I want to be able to access the API in a **console app** (and later a Windows gui app), when the user is logged into the company domain (domain joined).

**Progress so far:**

The API runs in the following App Service in Azure Portal: `MyWebApi`.

In addition, I have created the following App Registrations in Azure Portal:

- `MyWebApiClient`
- `MyWebApi`

I can access the Microsoft Graph API using IWA if I use the method described in this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-iwa-v2. Here I only use `MyWebApiClient` from above to access Microsoft Graph.

But can someone explain in steps how I can use IWA to protect and access my own API? The sample I linked to above, doesn't show how to setup the API in Azure to work with IWA & Azure AD.

Comment: What type of windows integrated auths and you want that from browser?

Comment: I don't think you can use IWA in App Service since I think IWA requires the server to be domain-joined.

Comment: @Dai My web service runs on Azure in an Azure Active Directory. The audience is Windows users on the AD connected through LAN or the company VPN.

Comment: @Dai The azure sample explicitly says it uses IWA *on domain joined or AAD joined machines*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow you mentioned is server-to-server. It is similar with [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) flow.

So, you could go to your API on portal and click `Authentication / Authorization` and turn on it. Choose `Login in with Azure Active Directory` and associate with your `MyWebApi`. Then it will be related with the api.

For more details you could refer to this article [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication).